# /welcomePrimefaces.xhtml @18,39 <p:layout> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: layoutl

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml

I was writing the first entity class in the entity package but I didn't want to delete te WelcomePrimefaces because I want to use it to try how to use some codes in it. The WelcomePrimefaces was working well but after I wrote the first Entity Class WelcomePrimeces didn't work.
I get this...
/welcomePrimefaces.xhtml @18,39 <p:layout> Tag Library supports namespace: http://primefaces.org/ui, but no tag was defined for name: layout

I have not change the code it gives me from the begining so I would like to know what is happening here.
this is the code from 18 line.

```
            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                
                <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Header
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" closable="true" collapsible="true">
                    Footer
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="175" header="Left" collapsible="true">
                    <p:menu>
                        <p:submenu label="Resources">
                            <p:menuitem value="Demo" url="http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/home.jsf" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Documentation" url="http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Forum" url="http://forum.primefaces.org/" />
                            <p:menuitem value="Themes" url="http://www.primefaces.org/themes.html" />

                        </p:submenu>

                    </p:menu>
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                    Welcome to PrimeFaces
                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>
```

I was expecting netbeans show me the error in the firt Entity Class I was doing, not the error in WelcomePrimefaces.

I alredy have the pool conexion well done to the database with Mysql and persistence with EclipseLink

I am using netbeans 15

Answer (score 0):

Layout was removed in PF 10.0.0 see: ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2168

You can use Layout from PrimeFaces Extensions: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/layout.jsf;